# What makes a question a "low-research-effort" question?

Tags: support

This is a follow-up to this meta post: [How can I improve this question: "Birthdays of Maika, Kaho, Mafuyu, Miu, Hideri"](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4343/how-can-i-improve-this-question-birthdays-of-maika-kaho-mafuyu-miu-hideri?newreg=3f2ae243ba3d4386a9ee8386e2c63c5f)

Guess who's here?  It's me!  I have returned to the site after a two-month break period.

The answer says:

> You asked a question that would have been easy to find after a cursory internet search. To some people your question shows a lack of research effort and implies you are attempting to push the question towards a particular answer. If you know one date, you do not explain why you could not find the other birthdates, or at least what is preventing you from doing your own research to find them.

How is this a "low-research-effort" question?

I've always considered a "low-research-effort" question means:

1. Questions that can be answered with the first link when searching its exact title on Google
2. Answer to the question can be found on a relevant Wikipedia article
3. Duplicate questions

But how does THIS one become such?

I search it's exact title on Google, this pops up:

> [image]

It *kind of* fits #1, but not *quite.*

And while the answer can be found on the Blend S Wiki, it's not found on Wiki**pedia**.

Nor this is a dupe.

How does this become a "low-research-effort" question then?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are again trying to push a particular argument based on preexisting personal biases. Lack of effort, broadly defined, can include, but is not limited to a result that may show up on the first page of search results, such as the Amino link.

It should be noted that you do not define any obstacles impeding progress or effort that can otherwise be done yourself. Your question comes off as sounding biased and/or self-selfing to other users who would have easily found the same information by taking a few minutes to do their own research work. The expected usage of question and answer sites such as Stack Exchange is for users to find solutions to problem they are typically unable to resolve by themselves. Your question is one that any user able to use an internet search engine can find with little to no effort.

Many users may question your intent as it comes off as your trying to bring up a particular topic to drive discussion on a certain topic (even if you are to deny) by asking a question that is easily answerable, not requiring much research effort or technical expertise (e.g. What color is Y main character's hair from the popular series X).

It's akin to asking someone to hand you an object that is within your reaching distance because you are unwilling to make the effort yourself. People here volunteer their time and effort to provide answers to problems other uses have. These trivial pursuits on low effort questions detract from and dilute the efforts made by those that are legitimately trying to find solutions to questions they cannot find answers to themselves and those that attempt to provide solutions to those questions.

If you truly and sincerely are unable to find solutions to these seemingly simple and easy to find question, at least take some time to explain why/where/how you struggle finding an answer. Showing that you at least made an effort yourself if better than not doing so.

With that said your particular gravitation towards a particular series makes us infer that your intent is more so to drum up attention to a particular set of series and topics than to address an existing issue. In other words, a solution in search of a problem.

I am again trying to break things down and explain them for one last time. Further escalation of matters (related this and previous meta posts) from you will be dismissed with prejudice moving forward. If your are still unsatisfied, you may bring it up further with the Stack Exchange Community Team via the contact form linked at the footer or at `team@stackoverflow.com` or `team@stackexchange.com`.

We have attempted to explain ourselves and find compromise, but your incessant stubbornness here and on other Stack Exchange communities have left us with no other reasonable discourse. We will forced move to censure if pressed futher.

Comment: It's clear that this conversation is going nowhere. I am locking the comments. This discussion has ended. If you are dissatisfied with thing, please voice your concerns to the community team via the contact methods provided in the above answer.